# Pivotal Server not lift in STS 3.6.1

Tags: spring-tool-suite

when I try to lift the server pivotal in STS 3.6.1, I get the following error:

```
Publishing the configuration...
Error copying file to C:/Spring-Tool-Suite/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.0.RELEASE/base-instance/backup\catalina.policy: C:\Spring-Tool-Suite\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.0.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\catalina.policy (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
C:\Spring-Tool-Suite\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.0.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\catalina.policy (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
```

and again....

The strange thing is that I started doing when I did a fresh install of STS

Comment: you marked this as solved, can you post a comment about how you fixed this?

Comment: Yes martin, in the followin answer is the solution

Answer (score 0):

I apologize to everyone, but I solved it as follows:

I renamed the workspace STS

I performed a fresh installation of STS

I imported the projects, and the server started smoothly.

Perhaps it was his own mistake of a novice like me.

Thank you very much.